# How do I see how many custom tabs have been created?

Tags: limits, tab

[image]I'm trying to create a new custom tab via setup -> appsetup -> create -> tabs. How can I get the exact count for the custom tabs, because I can see only 18 tabs, but it throws an error about the custom tab limit being exceeded?

Comment: Nikkey, are you able to include a exact quote of the error and/or a screenshot and description at what stage of tab creation you get this message ? Providing more details related to the issue will help us answer you.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke,@Jenny B,@Ankit Khandelwal :Thanks for your reply
:I have created a Custom object as :CustomLineItem ,when i clicked on the TAB , i could not see the custom object and it throws an Error as Custom Tab limit exceeded.In User Interface i could see it as 100% ,But when check thru the navigation i do get a count of 18.

Comment: Are there web tabs and visualforce tabs? In total you may have more than allowed but if the tabs are created by publicly managed packages on the app exchange, those do not count against your limit. There is an idea to make it more visible as to which tabs count against the limit, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxI6AAI. One user used their sandbox to delete one by one to see which ones where counting towards their limits.

Comment: The IdeaExchange Link in the above comment is moved to a new URL below https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYHIUA3/custom-tabs-indicate-which-tabs-count-against-your-org-custom-tab-limit

Answer (score 5):

[image]Click on Setup, then scroll down to the "Monitor" section and click on System Overview, you will see the limits on the right hand side. Custom Object Tabs, Web Tabs and VF Tabs all count against the limit. Tabs that are from public managed packages from the App Exchange, do not count against the limit. (The tabs with the managed installed icon, should not be counted).
[image]

Comment: If this limit is reached, can it be increased by salesforce support/contract changes ?

Comment: It can be increased, but tab limit is edition-related, so would require change to contract. In the old "unlimited edition" this was one of the actual unlimited things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in workbench to get the tab metadata.  please make sure to run this as a System admin.

/services/data/v31.0/tabs

It will give all information related to tab in your org. Hope it helps. thanks.