# Tab limit exceed, how to check the most/less visited tabs and the actual tabs

Tags: rest-api, administration, limits, tab

This is slightly different question to the one asked on [How do I see how many custom tabs have been created?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51432/how-do-i-see-how-many-custom-tabs-have-been-created) and I think it could be handy.

I have the same issue as him, I have more custom tabs that my limit. Before I request to hopefully get a limit increase on the number of tabs, I want to get rid of the one that probably are not used.

Someone mentioned that using Using Event Monitoring, could help to check which are the most visited URI, but this [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) link doesn't offer much information.

It is also quite confusing the workbench, as it displays a total of 74 tabs,
Even more confusing the custom tabs in set up,

([I am unable to upload the image, but this is the link to it](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/jdl-system/custom+tabs.jpg))

that between custom objects, Visualforce tabs and web tabs it shows me a total of 49, and 5 of them doesn't belong to a manage package (as they don't have the white/blue icon).

Has anyone been able to get the list of the most visited tabs?
Also, is there a way to clearly see which are the tabs are been count in this limit, because as I mention, either the workbench or the setup menu shows clearly this value.

Comment: n.b. Event Monitoring is extra cost item - http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2015/03/event-monitoring-quick-start-guide.html - the UI_TRACKING_EVENT and URI_EVENT might be useful to you